# activator value echoSettings

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

I'm trying run activator on my centos remote server and I got

```
activator-sbt-echo-akka-shim.sbt:1: error: not found: value echoSettings
echoSettings
^
[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Which version of activator are you using? Are you running activator inside a project or outside? If you are trying to run a project provide your build.sbt file.

Comment: activator-1.2.12, I'm runing inside the folder project

Comment: did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when building with TeamCity, after a commit. Turned out that I accidentally removed from my VCS the following files:

```
project/activator-sbt-echo-shim.sbt
project/activator-sbt-eclipse-shim.sbt
project/activator-sbt-idea-shim.sbt
project/build.properties
project/plugins.sbt
```

When I re-added the files, the build was successful. I'd suspect the first one to be the cause, but I haven't experimented any further.